# Algebraic solutions of the first order PDE

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following first order PDE:
$$
x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0.
$$
We are interested only in rational functions, that is, $f$ is quotient of two polynomials in $x,y,z$ (and we do the differentiation formally, i. e. we don't bother with singularities, zeroes in denominators, etc.)

**Question.** Can we conclude from this information that $f$ is of the form $f(x,y,z)=g(xy,xz)$, where $g(u,v)$ is a rational function of $u$ and $v$?

The motivation is as follows: in standard situation (say, in neighbourhood of some point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where functions $h_1(x,y,z)=xy$ and $h_2(x,y,z)=xz$ are independent) we have $f(x,y,z)=g(xy,xz)$ for some differentiable function $g(u,v)$.

For example, it's easy to check that all such functions are satisfying the PDE above:
$$
x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z)-z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z)=
\\
=xy\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(xy,xz)+xz\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(xy,xz)-yx\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(xy,xz)-zx\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(xy,xz)=0.
$$

However, we are looking only for "algebraic soultions", so $g$ *should be* a rational function (at least, I think so).